# phone gap registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode6

I found lots of links where people have given options to solve this problem but i dint understand how to resolve this issue.

Allow me explain my project from scratch.

I am using Xcode 6.0 and phonegap latest version. I have added PushPlugin from github

Once i run the project i am betting this error "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later."

Can some body help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: which version of PhoneGap / cordova are you using?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann phonegap 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

[When I look in PushPlugin's code](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/PushPlugin.m), I see that it *should* be handling the iOS 8 case correctly:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UserNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
    }
#else
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
#endif
```

Now I fetched this from a **fork** of [the original PushPlugin repo](https://github.com/bobeast/PushPlugin-deprecated).

You should 1) look in your PushPlugin.m file to make certain that the code is handling the iOS 8 case and 2) if not, you should fetch [an iOS 8 compatible version of the PushPlugin repo](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).